# php build asynchronous file upload api service

Tags: php, android, ios, api, data-synchronization

I built a cloud disk system based on third-party cloud storage. The upload process is as follows:

[image]

Now I want to asynchronousize the third-party service callback verification initiated by my server. The reason is: callback this step, I need to verify whether it is a callback request initiated by a third-party server, and I need to write the file information to the database. Time-consuming tasks, so I hope that in the callback this step, as long as the basic verification, will immediately give the third-party server a response to a successful response. But if I join the queue, or I immediately gave the client a successful response, but the client needs to be able to see the file immediately, but the successful status information I responded to will be invalidated. This is similar to a spike scenario. I grabbed the product, but the asynchronous processing failed. I was notified that I didn't grab it. How can I solve it